# Http_Request2 POST request not working

Tags: php, httprequest

Good morning fellows. I'm doing some work with Http_Request2 lib and I'm facing this situation. Im trying to make a POST request to certain URL. If I add the parameters on the query string of the url, i.e.

```
$request->setUrl('127.0.0.1/something.php?parm1=x&parm2=y');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
```

It works fine, but I want to set the parameters with the addPostParameter method:

```
$request->setUrl('127.0.0.1:8888/something.php');
$request->addPostParameter('parm1', $somevariable);
$request->addPostParameter($some_array_with_parms);
```

This way doesnt work. The URL indeed is to localhost port 8888.

Is something that I'm missing? Some type of configuration for POST request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```
try {

    $request = new HTTP_Request2('http://127.0.0.1:8888/something.php');
    $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
        ->addPostParameter('parm', 'value1') //single param
        ->addPostParameter(array('parmType' => 'val11','parm2' => 'val12')); //multiple
    $response = $request->send()->getBody();

} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
```

Note: make sure the port 8888 is open.

Comment: I had to add the first parm after the url on the querystring, then I added the sample code and worked. I'll accept your answer although someone else posted the same answer but erased.. thanks a lot

Comment: This does not work for me. It looks like the POST parameters are ignored.