# HTTP_Request2 POST parameters ignored?

Tags: php, post, http-request2

A query with curl, like this, works fine:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query":"porges","start":0,"rows":10,"lang":"ENGLISH"}' http://localhost:8080/services/rest/index/z56508/search/field/search
```

I my case I get 11 hits there. However when I try to translate this to HTTP_Request2 the call returns all hits in database instead.

I have looked at [Http_Request2 POST request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382850/http-request2-post-request-not-working) to write the code here:

```
    require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
    $url = "http://localhost:8080/services/rest/index/z56508/search/field/search";
    $data = array("query"=>"porges","start"=>"0","rows"=>"10","lang"=>"ENGLISH");

    $r = new HTTP_Request2($url);
    $r->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    $r->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
            ->addPostParameter($data);
    $response = $r->send();
    $body = $response->getBody();
    echo $body;
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like `"query" => "porges"` is ignored, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Friendly Manual: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php#package.http.http-request2.request.body

`addPostParameter()` should be used when you want to generate a POST request body according to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` Content-Type rules (hint: this is not JSON you are trying to send). If you have a pre-built request body, use `setBody()`:

```
$request->setBody('{"query":"porges","start":0,"rows":10,"lang":"ENGLISH"}');
```